# Unbind a driver from PCIe device on windows

Tags: windows, drivers, pci-express

To unbind a driver from the device on Linux, we can use `echo 0000:00:dev > /sys/bus.../unbind`.

This just unbinds the driver from device and we don't need to uninstall the entire driver.

I want to do similar thing on Windows. I searched this forum but couldn't find anything for Windows. Can someone please help me out with it.

Comment: you cant unbind it in the same way you do on linux, you either need to disable the device o uninstall it, but it doesn't really uninstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the device was using another driver previously, you can use the "Roll Back Driver" button under Computer > Properties > Device Manager > (device) > Properties > Driver.

If the button is not available, click the "Update Driver..." button instead, then "Browse my computer for driver software", then "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer", and select something other than the currently installed driver.

If for some reason you don't want to use a different driver **and** you don't want disable the device **and** you don't want to uninstall the driver from the system... this is not possible in Windows as far as I know.